# User and password not working when trying to access the host manager in Apache Tomcat/9.0.75

Tags: xml, authentication, server, localhost, tomcat9

I need help with this. I can't login in the host manager with the user and password I've already set in the file.

My tomcat-users.xml has this

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
```

My manager.xml has this

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" >
  <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                   sameSiteCookies="strict" />
  <!--Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /-->
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

I've restarted the server after every change I did to the users file

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code